# Divergent series $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } (2 k+1)^{3 k+1} z^k$ and LambertW function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I can get values from the following function,
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } (2 k+1)^{3 k+1} z^k $$

[image]
could you tell me how you could check those values using the Lambert function in  integral form or if you can tell me where I could find papers( I see before), it must be using the Lambert function in series mode and applying the borel transformation something like that, I have tried maple and it gives values for sum of this type for nagative values but not for this

Comment: `SumConvergence[(3 k + 1)^(3 k + 1)*z^k, k]` results in `z==0`. Maybe, some regularization (see https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Divergent+series&title=Special:Search&ns0=1) works here, but not [Mathematica's ones](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Regularization.html?q=Regularization).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results with Mathematica version 13.;3.  Instead, Mathematica returns `ComplexInfinity`.  For instance, `NSum[(2 k + 1)^(3 k + 1) 1^k, {k, 0, Infinity}]`.

Comment: Thanks @bbgodfrey I also used maple and there are not result, but using leving transform it is possible get some values for sum as K^k por z values negatives .

Answer (score 1):

The radius of the circle of convergency around z=0 is zero

```
  Limit[((2 k + 1)^(3 k + 1))^(1/k), k -> \[Infinity]]
  == Limit[(1 + 2 k)^((1/k + 3)), k -> \[Infinity]]
  ==\[Infinity]
```

$$k^{3k}/x^k ->\infty$$

at least starting for all $k>x^3$